# Error in glmer function

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

So I want to know if there is an effect of X, X' and/or X'' on Y. Y is a numerical variable and X, X', X'' are characters. I must also add individuals (ID) as a random effect.
To do this I looked at the distribution of my variable Y by a histogram. Its distribution looks like that of the gamma function. So to study its variation, I chose the glmer function of the package lme4 in R.
I realize several models with only an effect of X, X' or X'', with an interaction between X * X', X*X'' or X' * X'', and even with an interaction and a 'covariance': X*X '+ X''. I also made a null model.
My goal then is to compare all my models with an AIC.

Here is an example of my function in R :

```
fm18<-glmer(Y+0.1~X*X’+X’’+(1|ID),data=homerange,family=Gamma)
```

I had to do this for two different variables Y ... For the first everything works perfectly, but for the second I get this error for all my models:

```
Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L,
  (Maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
```

What does this error mean? What is it due to? How to correct it?